# Inner join when column has combination of two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know the title sucks, I just didn't know what else to use.

I have table `Employee`, that looks like this:

```
EmpId    EmpNum   Last
ABC      130      Smith
XVC      210      Johnson
ZAL      105      William
GFL      221      Miller
```

`Employee` will be joined to `EmpUpload`. The table looks like this. Column EmpId_Num can include EmpId or EmpNum:

```
EmpId_Num    First
221          Mary
XVC          James
GFL          Alicia
```

Since empnum and empid can never be the samer, a solution would be to use two ctes and then do a `union` of both results, something like below:

```
;with cte as
(
    select First, Last from Employee inner join EmpUpload on
    employee.empnum = empupload.empid_num
),
cte2 as 
(
    select First, Last from Employee inner join EmpUpload on
    employee.empid = empupload.empid_num
)
select first,last from cte union 
select first,last from cte2
```

Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you can use OR operators on Joins too!

```
select First, Last 
from Employee 
inner join EmpUpload on employee.empnum = empupload.empid_num
    OR employee.empid = empupload.empid_num
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks.